# MarkLogic Search API: Limited cts:search() scope to within objects in an array

Tags: marklogic

```
"array": [
    {
      "id": "000-1111",
      "url": "http://test.com",
      "name": "Fred"
    },
    {
      "id": "000-1111",
      "url": "http://test.com",
      "name": "Joe"
    },
    {
      "id": "000-1111",
      "url": "http://test2.com",
      "name": "Sarah"
    },
    {
      "id": "000-1111",
      "url": "http://test3.com",
      "name": "Sam"
    }
]
```

In the JSON example above, I am trying to match on the last object in the array, where the URL and name matches the exact same values I pass in, ***within the same object***. The problem in my data is this array can contain many of the same objects that have the exact same fields and values.

My current query:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), 
    cts:and-query((
      cts:json-property-value-query("url", "http://test3.com"),
      cts:json-property-value-query("name", "Sam")
    ))
)
```

This query returns false positive results when the array looks like this:

```
"array": [
    {
      "id": "000-1111",
      "url": "http://test3.com",
      "name": "Fred"
    },
    {
      "id": "000-1111",
      "url": "http://test.com",
      "name": "Sam"
    }
]
```

Is there a way with cts:queries to constrain your search to the scope of within the same object for JSON arrays?

This XPath method works against this datasets collection, but is not performant:

```
fn:collection("mydata")[array[url="http://test3.com"][name="Sam"]]
```

Is there a cts expression that is the equivalent of the above?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your array of `object-nodes()` are unnamed, and don't have a named field to anchor to, and can't constrain with `cts:json-property-scope-query()`

But you might be able to constrain the search and eliminate false-positives by applying a `cts:near-query()` to ensure that those properties are next to each other:

```
cts:search(doc(),
  cts:near-query(( 
    cts:json-property-value-query("name", "Sam"),
    cts:json-property-value-query("url", "http://test3.com")
  ), 1) 
)
```

Or you can apply a predicate filter to the search results, to eliminate the false positives.

```
let $name := "Sam"
let $url := "http://test3.com"
return
  cts:search(doc(), 
    cts:and-query(( 
      cts:json-property-value-query("name", $name),
      cts:json-property-value-query("url", $url)
    )) 
  )[array-node("array")/object-node()[name=$name and url=$url]]
```

Comment: Hi Mads than you for your response here... So the near-query() unfortunately returns the same false positive results. And the predicate filter to the search results takes as long as the collection query to finish evaluating... Will we have to resort to changing our data structure and make sure the objects in our arrays are named?

Comment: Check whether you have "word positions" and "element word positions" turned on. Those are needed for near queries to work unfiltered. If you have those and still get false positives, try adding the "ordered" option to the near query. If the order of the properties is reliable, that can prevent neighboring objects from getting matched together.

Comment: Hi Dave, so looks like the issue was my search was unfiltered, turning it to filtered was able to return me the correct resultset, although at slower speed. I did not need any of the indexes or the ordered option. Is there a way to get this working unfiltered?